# How to access cck fields in tpl file?

Tags: drupal-6, cck, drupal-theming

I am working on one already created drupal site. In themes folder it has one tpl.php file, Where theme is done to display the content. Now it is as follows

**print $content**

And all the fields of cck are displayed properly. But I want to access every field like Title, Body etc. I have tried with **$content['title']**, But nothing is displayed.

Can anyone please tell me how to access different fields in my tpl file. I am using Drupal 6.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try to

```
<pre>
 print_r($content);
</pre>
```

then you will see what's exactly in the array.

Comment: That is the problem. I already tried it. But it is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use node-[type].tpl.php to see the different fields. There, by default, each CCK field is exposed in a variable named with the field's name, for example if you have a field called `field_logo` then you have a variable called `$field_logo` which is an array representing the field's processed values and can be `print_r()`'d.

More template suggestions are available in [Drupal documentation](http://drupal.org/node/1089642). And [more information on using node.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/6) and its derivatives is available too.